# Resistance vs capacitance of conductor

Tags: resistance, capacitance, transmission-line, conductors

Suppose we have a wire which transmits power. Is there a direct relationship between the resitance (or conductance) of the wire/m and the capacitance of the wire/m? Or they are independent of each other?

Comment: Self-capacitance of a single wire is typically not important compared to its capacitance in relation to other conductors nearby. The important capacitance depends much more on the arrangement of other nearby conductors than on things that determine the wire resistance (the diameter and material of the wire).

Comment: Do you actually mean a pair of wires forming a cable with forward and return current paths?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a direct relationship between the resistance (or conductance) of the wire/m and the capacitance of the wire/m? Or they are independent of each other?

There is no direct relationship, but there are practical generalities.

In terms of **capacitance**, a single wire can be very long and have little capacitance (in the vacuum of space) because nothing else is near it.  Incidentally, this wire will still have *some* capacitance associated with it, due to [self-capacitance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance), which is a function of the surface area; see the last formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance#Capacitance_of_conductors_with_simple_shapes).

Or it can have lots of capacitance (RG-405 Co-Ax for example) when another conductor is very close to it.  Capacitance is an inverse function of distance; the further conductors are from each other, generally the less capacitance per-unit-length results.

Since it is practical to keep more than one wire close together, each wire bundle will have a capacitance rating per-unit-length which is roughly inversely proportional to how close the conductors are inside.  The properties of the insulating material also matter, with better-performing materials generally being more expensive.

For example, the outer width of a [RG-405 co-axial cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coaxial_cable) is only 0.0865in/2.20mm wide; as a consequence its conductors are very close inside, which means it has a higher amount of capacitance-per-unit-length.  If a physically larger cable were constructed from the same materials, that would have less capacitance per-unit-length.

**Resistance** is solely a function of the metal's [conductivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity) per-unit-length.  In this link is a table of various metals and their conductivities.  Silver is one of the best electrical conductors; therefore any wire which is silver-plated will have less resistance per-unit-length than any other type (copper, aluminum, etc.)

All conductors can achieve zero resistance (superconductivity) if exposed to very cold temperatures approaching absolute zero.  This usually makes them extremely brittle so thus only finds uses in specialty applications.

Note that the reduction of resistance to zero, does not imply the same thing for capacitance - that *still exists* in superconductors.

In general, **the capacitance and resistance effects are independent of each other.**  But both are also unavoidable.  Since it is so common to place more than one wire in a bundle and to maintain some sort of standard for how this behaves (resistance and capacitance ratings), standards such as RG-405 were created.  This is so that manufacturers building this cable, and designers using this cable, will target these intrinsic values and build around them accordingly.